# Git Init for new project

Tags: node.js, git, mongodb, heroku, github

I'm a bit confused on "Git Init." I'm using Cloud9 for my projects. I had a previous project I worked on before that I cloned as a starting point for my new project. I'm currently in the process of pushing this new project to Heroku/Git. I do NOT want to override my previous project.

**Current Steps taken:**

- Cloned original project as a starting point for a new project
- Created new project with new code etc.
- Time to deploy. Created new Heroku link with heroku create
- Used git remote set-url heroku to change to new Heroku link
- Now I'm ready to push but don't want to override original project

Now I've done git add -A
and checked git status

Here is my problem and concern for the new project's files it says "new files" but for my previous project's files it says "delete files"

```
new file:   views/listings/show.ejs
new file:   views/listings/sold.ejs
deleted:    views/profile.ejs
deleted:    views/rentals/edit.ejs
deleted:    views/rentals/editprofile.ejs
```

I do not want to delete any files from my previous project I only want to create a new repo. I'm confused and concerned that if I push my new project I will delete my old project.

Any clarification is greatly appreciated!

Thanks so much!

Comment: Are the files git says are deleted in your working directory?

Comment: @Mark_M Hey there! Those files are in a previous directory. I do not want to be pushing new files or removing files anywhere near my original project or directory. The goal is to create a new heroku app and git directory for this project.

Comment: "*and switched the remote to use that app*" ... why did you switch the remote? That's not the right way to do that. If you have a different repo, then you should clone it to a different directory. Don't switch the remote unless you are working on the same project but you've changed servers.

Answer (score 1):

Possible Solution:

- Within C9 I copied the project folder and pasted it into a new folder
- Then I deleted the "Git" Folder within the copied project (Removing Master)
- Then I followed Heroku's advice and did the following:

  $ cd my-project/ 
   $ git init $ 
   $ heroku git:remote -a starklight-meadow-random

I doubled checked using git remote -v that I was going to push to the correct Heroku project.

All looks good when checking git status. Only added files to an empty repo.

Answer (score 0):

Ah... I now see from your updates that you are using one project as a starting point for another project.

If you change the remote, then you will not affect the original repo *on the server*. You will be affecting your local repo, but I think that's what you want.

If this is a brand new project and you don't have anyone else working on it, then you should be able to push the current repo to the server using `--force` to essentially force the server to use your current repo's state. This flag can have dire consequences if not used properly, so I suggest reading up on it before using it.

Another option, which may be easier, is to simply clone the new repo, delete files you don't want to keep, then copy-paste your files from the other repo. There are more complicated ways of achieving the same result, but this will give you a cleaner history and will probably be more intuitive for you.

---

Old Answer:

> ...and **switched the remote** to use that app

If you are going to work on a different project contained in a different repo, then you **should not** switch the remote of your current repo. You should clone the second repo into a different directory.

When you switched the remote, you basically said... "*Hey, you know all that work on the other server? Well just ignore that, because this is what the project should look like now.*"

You should restore your original remote and run `git clone` to a new directory.

Comment: Hey @JDB thanks for the help. I've added steps to explain what I've currently done. Does your advice still stand?

Comment: Note: I'm not changing my remote of my previous project only my new project

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I like the thought about cloning the repo. I do feel like I'm walking on egg shells to not delete my previous project though.

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi - It's pretty difficult to truly delete anything in git. It's possible, but not as easy as you might think. Either approach should be fine, but I like the idea of cloning the target repo and then changing the source code to what I want it to be. It's just a lot more intuitive and easier for me to keep it all straight.

Comment: Thoughts on my solution below?